# Algorithm for beanstalkd queue

Tags: algorithm, mongoose, beanstalkd

I am processing huge amount of parcels for tracking. I have mongodb in which each users have different parcels. There are more than 20 companies(tnt,fedex,dhl etc) and each company only allows single tracking or  batch tracking with a limit (e.g tnt=1, fedex=20 and dhl=10)

I am trying to find a way to queue the tracking jobs which effectively uses the batch processing. For example if I have total 50 fedex jobs, 3 tnt jobs and 11 dhl jobs, I want to queue them like below

```
[fedex job:[20 jobs]][fedex job:[20 jobs]][fedex job:[10 jobs]]
[tnt job:[1 job]][tnt job:[1 job]][tnt job:[1 job]]
[dhl job:[10 job]][dhl job:[1 job]]
```

How can I achieve above job scenario?

**EDIT**

I want to able to run this on beanstalkd with a single or multiple workers. Therefore independent state is very important. Beanstalkd jobs should look like below,

```js
{
'slug':'fedex'
'trackingNumbers':[11,22,33....] //20
}

{
'slug':'tnt'
'trackingNumbers':[11,22,33....] //10
}

{
'slug':'dhl'
'trackingNumbers':[11] //1
}

{
'slug':'tnt'
'trackingNumbers':[11,22,33....] //10
}

{
'slug':'fedex'
'trackingNumbers':[11,22,33....] //20
},

{
'slug':'dhl'
'trackingNumbers':[11] //1
}
```

I don't know really maybe there is a MongoDB function to aggregate parcels of each users to above chunks.

Here is my Mongoose Models

```js
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, index: {unique: true, sparse: true}},
    password: String,
    createdOn: {type: Date, default:Date.now },
    purchaseDate:Date,
    expiryDate:Date,
    purchaseID: {type: String, index: {unique: true, sparse: true}},
    isEnabled: {type: Boolean,default: true}
});

UserSchema.virtual('parcels',{
    ref: 'Parcel',
    localField:'_id',
    foreignField:'owner'
});

var ParcelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    owner : { type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    dna:String,
    name: String,
    count: {type: Number, default: 1},
    trackingNumber: String,
    slug:String,
    isDelivered: {
        type: Boolean, default: false
    },
    startDate: {type: Date, default:Date.now },

    updateDate: Date,
    finishDate: Date,
    expectedDate: Date,
    extra:String,
    details:[{
        _id:false,
        message: String,
        location: String,
        date: Date,
        status: Number
    }]
});
```

Comment: From what I understood you just need to divide the total number jobs to the limit, round up to the nearest integer (e.g. ceil(50/20)=3) to get the number of batches, then fill up all batches except maybe the last...

Comment: I don't have problems with dividing the jobs if I had them in single bucket. Imagine there are thousands of users with millions of jobs. The thing is jobs are distributed among users, I don't know how to get those jobs from several users and divide. I can't get a solution to effectively batch the jobs.

Comment: I don't see how "beanstalkd" will help you. You need a kind of fixed thread pool scheduler (the term from Java) and the choice obviously depends on the programming language you are using.

Comment: Beanstalk will help me for following issues. After I queue the jobs, a) I can run multiple workers from different machines, b) I can retry the jobs(bury,retry) if I can't reach the web site c) I can delete the job if it fails multiple times etc. My problem is how get tracking jobs from different users and pushing to the queue.

Comment: So you want a distributed state? That's a completely different requirement, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a suggestion. You could do the following:

- have a tube per delivery company, e.g. `fedex`, `dhl`, etc.
- have one worker attached to only one queue (but you may have as many workers as you would like)
- every worker should use Beanstalkd's `stats-tube <tube>` command before `reserve`. `stats-tube` returns the number of currently reserved jobs in this queue (field `current-jobs-reserved` in YAML output of the command)
- so your worker makes sure it doesn't violate SLA for the queue it processes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to get jobs for lets say from MongoDb according to the properties of company. Fedex tube must be filled with jobs which must have 20 tracking number inside. This way I can run workers independent of each other and I can process 20 tracking numbers. If I understand you correctly, you tell me to stats-tube continuously and when it reaches, 20 reserve twenty jobs but it will be very hard to reserve 20 jobs if there were 5 workers let say watching the same fedex tube.